# How to pass a variable to a kivy widget property?

Tags: python, kivy

I know this is a common question and there are several answers on this topic, but none of them work for me so here it goes:

I am trying to have a font size defined in main.py under class of the Container(BoxLayout) and then use that value in .kv file to drive the size of font dynamically.

I had another example of using a string property this way for text and it works, but when it comes to Numeric or Object Properties it just does not.

Here is the code:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty

class Container(BoxLayout):
    user_name = StringProperty('Mad Max')
    y = ObjectProperty('100dp')

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv**

```
<Container>:
    Label:
        text: root.user_name
        font_size: root.y
```

As this already works for string files I am without a clue of what to do!

Thank you for your time answering this!

Goodbye

Comment: Your `kivy file for the IntroScreen` does not mention `IntroScreen`. Is that a typo? Also, as it stands, the `root.y` refers to the `y` attribute of `BoxLayout`, probably not what you wanted.

Comment: I did not include the whole code in kivy. The point is everything works and runs fine if I use for example '50dp', but if I use root.y the text is as small as 1 pixel. String property however gets read normaly with root.x. I will edit this to show the whole kivy file if that helps.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: John Anderson you just solved the problem for me :-) I just changed the name of the variable to something else than y and now it works. I would still like to know why the name (y) made this an issue but still thank you.

Comment: If it still makes sense to edit the question and make it minimal, complete and verifiable, I can do that...

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful for others who may find this question. The problem with using `x` or 'y' is that those attributes are the position of a `Widget`, so your font size would depend on the position of the `IntroScreen`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here was the problem:

I should not have used a variable name like "y". As **John Anderson** pointed out, using "x" or "y" as a name for a variable name conflicts with Widgets as those names are used for positioning.

So the code should just use a better name for a variable, like:

**main.py**

```
title_size = ObjectProperty('50dp')
```

**main.kv**

```
font_size: root.title_size
```

**So just don't use "x" or "y" for a name of a variable!**

Thank you

> John Anderson

and hope this helps others.

Bye